# jsch jar virus problems

Tags: android, jsch, trojan

I'm having some trouble with the JAR file for the jsch library. Each time I run my Android Studio Project and then carry out a Microsoft Security Essentials scan I am returned with this result

> Category: Trojan
>
> Description: This program is dangerous and executes commands from an
>   attacker.
>
> Recommended action: Remove this software immediately.
>
> Items: 
>   containerfile:C:\ path to android studio project \app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\jsch-0.1.52 (1)-ba0826120a3d91778da515a6d356271502469056.jar
>
> file:C:\path to android studio project \app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\jsch-0.1.52 (1)-ba0826120a3d91778da515a6d356271502469056.jar->classes.dex
>
> Get more information about this item online.

The url the information brings me to is [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?name=Trojan%3AAndroidOS%2FFakeLook.A&threatid=2147666618&enterprise=0)

Does anybody know how to remedy this or has anyone come up against this before? Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Where did you download the jar from?

Comment: @Kenster From the official jsch site. I've done some more research and I think it may be a false positive on the part of Microsoft Security Essentials. Still not entirely sure though.